# Trying to join two independent forms

Tags: symfony1

i'm trying to join two independent forms (login and register) in the
same page.

My idea is (just looking at the signin form):

- Create an action that shows both forms (partials):

  ```
  public function executeLoginAndRegister(sfWebRequest $request){

     $this->form_signin =  $this->getUser()->getAttribute('form_signin');

  }
  ```
- Each partial calls to its action:

> form action="php?> echo url_for('@sf_guard_signin') ?>" method="post">

- In the actions i write this code

  ```
  public function executeSignin($request)
  {
     //...

    $this->form = new $MyFormclass();

     if ($this->form->isValid())
     {
         //...

     }else{

          // save the form to show the error messages.
          $this->getUser()->setAttribute('form_signin', $this->form);

          return $this->forward('sfGuardAuth', 'loginAndRegister');

      }
  }
  ```

It works, but, for example, if i execute LoginAndRegister and submit
incorrectly the signin form and I go to another page and then return to
LoginAndRegister, i will find the submiting error messages...

If i execute LoginAndRegister and submit incorrectly the signin form and
open another browser tab, i will find the submiting error messages in
the signin form of the second tab...

Any idea? any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it, just writing in the if "request->isMethod('post')":

```
 public function executeLoginAndRegister(sfWebRequest $request){

    if($request->isMethod('post')){

    $this->form_signin =  $this->getUser()->getAttribute('form_signin');

  }
}
```

Anyway if my approach has any big error or is not safety i would
thank anyone who tell me.

Javi

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [sfDoctrineApplyPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineApplyPlugin/1_0_1) if i were you :)

Comment: I'm using sfDoctrineGuardExtraPlugin to register users. It works perfect. I think my problem is not that. My problem is placing independent forms in the same page.

Comment: No, I'm NOT embedding both forms into a single form. Do you think embedding both forms would work? But they are totally independents! :S